# unable to lookup using xslt template match

Tags: xslt

In bpel we are implementing a transformation using XSLT. Below are 2 source XML files and desired target. I have applied identity match template to copy source2 to target as a first stage. I am unable to achieve the desired output by any match templates. The source 1 (lookup) can be accessed as `$lookup` in the XSLT.

Source1(look up):

```
<Lookup>
<values>
      <val>1</val>
      <val>2</val>
</values>
</Lookup>
```

Source2 (Primary)

```
<req>
<ref>
    <id>True</id>
    <val>1</val>
</ref>
<ref>
    <id>True</id>
    <val>2</val>
</ref>
<ref>
    <id>True</id>
    <val>1234</val>
</ref>
</req>
```

Target

```
<req>
<ref>
    <id>False</id>
    <val>1</val>
</ref>
<ref>
    <id>False</id>
    <val>2</val>
</ref>
<ref>
    <id>True</id>
    <val>1234</val>
</ref>
</req>
```

---

The lookup can be accessed as `$lookup` in the XSLT.
I used XSLT identity template to copy from source(primary) to target, but I am unable to break through with the rest of the match patterns with template matches.

Comment: Does bpel support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Please explain the *logic* that needs to be applied here.

Comment: I need source2 as is in the target,except with the condition if <value> in source and lookup match,the corresponding <idshould> should be set to false in the target.if it doesn't match, the value of I'd should remain true

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="Lookup/values/val" use="."/>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="ref[key('ref', val, $lookup)]/id">
  <id>False</id>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the identity transformation template.

With XSLT 1.0 you can't use the variable in a match pattern and the `key` function does not have that argument to change the context, so not using a key you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="lookup" select="document('source1.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref/id">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../val = $lookup//val">
                <id>False</id>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```